# powershell download file from delayed Link

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to download a msi Package from a Page which does a redirection in the background which downloads the file I want.

This is the Page I want to download the msi from:
https://remotedesktopmanager.com/de/home/thankyou/rdmmsi

I tried several PowerShell Scripts, but none of them extracted the right download URL or downloaded the file.
With `Invoke-Webrequest -Outfile C:xxx` only the HTML is saved.

Comment: Can't you get the redirection URL with your navigator devtools and use it directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the page uses javascript with a timeout to redirect to the current setup file. that's why you cannot use `Invoke-WebRequest` as this uses the Internet Explorer engine under the hood which also performs this javascript `window.location` redirect (resulting in opening the url in the default browser).

To only get the raw HTML you have to use `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
$website = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://remotedesktopmanager.com/de/home/thankyou/rdmmsi'
```

The full website is now stored in the variable `$website` without interpreting the javascript.
To find the line with the string `window.location` i use `Select-String`  which requires a file to be parsed. Thus the content of the variable is first stored in the file which is then parsed.

```
$tmpFilePath = 'C:\tmp\t.txt'
Out-File -FilePath $tmpFilePath -InputObject $website
$urlRedirectLine = Select-String -Path $tmpFilePath -SimpleMatch "window.location"
Remove-Item -Path $tmpFilePath
```

The new variable `$urlRedirectLine` (which content now is `C:\tmp\t.txt:999:            setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'https://cdn.devolutions.net/download/Setup.RemoteDesktopManager.2021.1.25.0.msi'; }, 4500);`) contains the string we are looking for.

To extract that url i convert to variable to string and then use `SubString()` to extract the url itself. For this i look for the first `'` and last `'` in that variable.

```
$urlString = $urlRedirectLine.ToString()
$url = $urlString.Substring($urlString.IndexOf("'")+1,$urlString.LastIndexOf("'")-$urlString.IndexOf("'")-1)
```

Resulting in `$url` having the url `https://cdn.devolutions.net/download/Setup.RemoteDesktopManager.2021.1.25.0.msi`

To download the file you can again use `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile 'C:\tmp\rdm.msi'
```

Comment: Dude, this is the exact answer I was searching for. Huge Thanks to you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar error while trying to download httpd.

Following worked for me (-UserAgent "NativeHost")

```
$ENV:HTTPD_DOWNLOAD_URL = "https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VS16/binaries/httpd-2.4.52-win64-VS16.zip"
$ENV:HTTPD_DOWNLOAD_ZIP = "httpd.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ENV:HTTPD_DOWNLOAD_URL -OutFile $ENV:HTTPD_DOWNLOAD_ZIP -UserAgent "NativeHost";
```

Reference
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23fccc30-5f84-4a84-8160-c6e95102b11c/powershell-invokewebrequest-sourceforge-urlsredirectiondynamic-content?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score -1):

The Link you give is of main download page which redirects after few second to the download.

The downloading link is `"https://cdn.devolutions.net/download/Setup.RemoteDesktopManager.2021.1.25.0.msi"`

Use the following command to download that MSI.

```
$url = "https://cdn.devolutions.net/download/Setup.RemoteDesktopManager.2021.1.25.0.msi"
$dest = "C:\Setup.RemoteDesktopManager.2021.1.25.0.msi"
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $dest
```

You can also use Invoke-WebRequest using the above variable

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest`

Thank You